# error_get_last() doesn't show last warning

Tags: 7

Drupal has its own custom error handler, so when I try to get the message from the last warning (e.g. for an invalid regex), there is nothing there:

```
if (@preg_match($regex, NULL) === FALSE) {
  dpm(error_get_last());
}
```

The `@` prevents it from being displayed on the screen, and without that I can see a warning for a $regex of `'/(/'` (about an unmatched paren), but the warning is not shown by `dpm()`, but rather by Drupal.

Is there a way I can get the warning from an invalid regex in this example, so that I could have the message in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same PHP's error functions as Drupal to toggle PHP's error handling behavior.

In particular, you can use [`set_error_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) / [`restore_error_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.restore-error-handler.php) to toggle the PHP error code handling while you're debugging:

```
// Remove _drupal_error_handler() handling
restore_error_handler();

if (@preg_match($regex, NULL) === FALSE) {
  dpm(error_get_last());
}
// Restore _drupal_error_handler() handling
set_error_handler('_drupal_error_handler');
```

See the PHP doc links for more information on how these error handling functions work.

Comment: This does technically answer my question, but it ended up not working, because I found out that the preg_match warning is thrown by the Drupal error handler. So restoring the error handler removed the warning completely.

Comment: I ended up using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1241751/2415524)